# Doctrine order by related entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I have 3 entities:

```yml
My\Bundle\Entity\Investment:
    type:  entity
    fields:
#       ...
    oneToMany:
        payouts:
            targetEntity: My\Bundle\Entity\Payout
            mappedBy: investment
            orderBy: {operation.effectiveDate: 'ASC'}

My\Bundle\Entity\Payout:
    type:  entity
    fields:
#       ...
    manyToOne:
        investment:
            targetEntity: My\Bundle\Entity\Investment
            inversedBy: payouts
        operation:
            targetEntity: My\Bundle\Entity\Operation
            inversedBy: payouts

My\Bundle\Entity\Operation:
    type:  entity
    fields:
        effectiveDate:
            type: datetime
#       ...
    oneToMany:
        payouts:
            targetEntity: My\Bundle\Entity\Payout
            mappedBy: operation
```

As you can see, an `investment` has multiple `payouts` which are attached to one `operation`

I'd like to get `investment.payouts` ordered by `payout.operation.effectiveDate`.

I tried to use `orderBy: {operation.effectiveDate: 'ASC'}` but it doesn't work.

So the question is:
**How can I order `investment.payouts` by `payout.operation.effectiveDate` ?**

Comment: Could you please show me the code of the query you are trying to execute?

Comment: `$em->find('MyBundle:Investment', 42)->getPayouts()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a repository function?

```
public function getPayouts() {

   $em = $this->getEntityManager();

   $sql = 'SELECT i, p, o '
          . 'FROM AppBundle:Investment i '
          . 'JOIN i.payouts p '
          . 'JOIN p.operation o '
          . 'ORDER BY o.effectiveDate ';

   $query = $em->createQuery($sql);

   return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can only use `orderBy` to order by a field directly on the child entity. Otherwise, you have to use a query to do it.

Comment: Yeah I'll have to use the repository... Thanks. I guess we can't `orderBy` related entity fields because this entity is not always joined at hydration time. Maybe the join should be forcable in that case.